# Quiz does not approve a good answer

Tags: c++

I'm making a quiz, where I want to load the questions and answers from a `txt` file.

When I ran this program, even though I chose a correct answer, it shows that it was incorrect.

For example, the first answer should be "c", and second should be "d".

I changed some of the text to English, but I think everything is understandable from the context.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>       //bibl your_answerialna za zapis (od file)
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string topic, nick;
string quest[5], odpA[5], odpB[5], odpC[5], odpD[5], correct[5];
string your_answer;
int punkty=0;

int main()
{
    string linia;
    int nr_linii=1;
    int nr_pytania=0;

    fstream plik;                       //zmienna plikowa tj nazwa pliku w kodzie zrodlowym + jej nazwa, moze byc ich wiele w programie

    plik.open("quiz.txt", ios::in);       //funcka otwarcia zmiennej plik (nazwa pliku , tryb otwarcia), ios:in tj wprowadz do programu

    if(plik.good()==false)                                   //funkcji z bibl fstrem sprawdzajaca czy plik istnieje

    {
        cout<<"nie ma takiego pliku";
        exit(0);        //zakonczenie programu z bibl <cstdlib>
    }



    while(getline(plik, linia))   //pobieramy linie do "linia"
    {
        switch(nr_linii)
        {
            case 1: topic=linia; break;
            case 2: nick=linia; break;
            case 3: quest[nr_pytania] = linia; break;
            case 4: odpA[nr_pytania] = linia; break;
            case 5: odpB[nr_pytania] = linia; break;
            case 6: odpC[nr_pytania] = linia; break;
            case 7: odpD[nr_pytania] = linia; break;
            case 8: correct[nr_pytania] = linia; break;
        }
        if(nr_linii==8) {
            nr_linii=2;
            nr_pytania++;
        }   //gdy program zczyta linie 8, wracamy do 8, i zwiekszamy nr pytania zapisujac jedo bibliotek
        nr_linii++;
    }
    plik.close();               //funkca zamykajaca


    for(int i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
        cout<<"your_answer on question"<<endl;
        cout<<quest[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"A "<<odpA[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"B "<<odpB[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"C "<<odpC[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"D "<<odpD[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"twoja odp";
        cin>>your_answer;

        transform(your_answer.begin(), your_answer.end(), your_answer.begin(), ::tolower);  //zamian duzych liter na male
        if (your_answer==correct[i])
        {
            cout<<"Dobrze! Zdobywasz punkt!"<<endl;
            punkty++;
        }
        else
            cout<<"Fail, no point,  correct answer is: "<<correct[i]<<endl;

    }

    cout<<"Koniec quizu. Zdobyte punkty: "<<punkty;
    return 0;
}
```

And [here's the text file](http://pastebin.com/e9CfUFdV) which I want to load.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I dont understand why program does not recognize the correct answer.

Comment: Most likely because there is a bug. As a programmer it is now your job to use the tools at your disposal to identify and resolve the bug.

Comment: the problem is that code higher works on windows, but not on ubuntu

Comment: gdb is a simple debugger for ubuntu

Comment: You may want to consider one array of a structure with 5 members.

Comment: IMHO, your program would be less complicated if you read the first two lines before entering the `while` loop.

Comment: FYI, you are allowed to use more than one `std::getline` in a while loop.  For example, you may want to have the loop read questions, and inside the loop, read each answer line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes:

1. correct[] to *char* type. Then needed to change case 8 and checking for correct answer to tolower().
2. Made file opening and error handling simpler. Removed exit(0) to abide to good programming practices

The code recognizes the correct answers now. Let me know if you still have troubles S.Grzejnik

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>       //bibl your_answerialna za zapis (od file)
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    string topic, nick;
    string parts[5][5]; //5 questions and 5 string parts to each one
    char correct[5];
    char your_answer;
    int punkty=0;

    int main()
    {
        string linia;

        ifstream plik;                       //zmienna plikowa tj nazwa pliku w kodzie zrodlowym + jej nazwa, moze byc ich wiele w programie

        plik.open("quiz.txt");       //funcka otwarcia zmiennej plik (nazwa pliku , tryb otwarcia), ios:in tj wprowadz do programu

        if(plik)                                   //funkcji z bibl fstrem sprawdzajaca czy plik istnieje
        {
            getline(plik, topic);
            getline(plik, nick);

            for(int pytanie = 0; pytanie < 5; pytanie++) {
                getline(plik, linia);
                for(int nr_linia = 0; nr_linia < 5; nr_linia++) {
                    parts[pytanie][nr_linia] = linia;
                    getline(plik, linia);
                }
                correct[pytanie] = linia[0];
            }
            plik.close();               //funkca zamykajaca

            for(int pytanie = 0; pytanie < 5; pytanie++)
            {
                    cout<<"your_answer on pytanieuestion"<<endl;
                    cout<<parts[pytanie][0]<<endl;
                    cout<<"A "<<parts[pytanie][1]<<endl;
                    cout<<"B "<<parts[pytanie][2]<<endl;
                    cout<<"C "<<parts[pytanie][3]<<endl;
                    cout<<"D "<<parts[pytanie][4]<<endl;

                    cout<<"twoja odp: ";
                    cin>>your_answer;

                    if (tolower(your_answer)==correct[pytanie])
                    {
                        cout<<"Dobrze! Zdobywasz punkt!"<<endl;
                        punkty++;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<"Fail, no point,  correct answer is: "<<correct[pytanie]<<endl;
                    }
            }

            cout<<"Koniec quizu. Zdobyte punkty: "<<punkty<<endl;
        }   
        else
        {
            cout<<"nie ma takiego pliku"<<endl;
            exit(0);        //zakonczenie programu z bibl <cstdlib>
        }

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now everything is simple and clear, thank you once again!

Comment: @S.Grzejnik I revised/improved the code while also incorporating some of the comments on your original question and updated this answer